# Git repository: deep copy

Tags: git

Suppose I have some git repository, `x`. I want to clone this repo into a new repo, called `x-new`. I don't want my changes to `x-new` to be pushed to `x`, and would rather have them pushed to the remote `x-new` repo. Basically, I want `x-new` not to know that `x` even exists.

Is such a "deep copy" mechanism possible in git? I haven't found a canonical example. Perhaps I'm not using the right verbiage, but "deep copy" is the best way I can think to describe what I need.

Comment: Are you trying to keep the repository history? If so, you would be changing the remote for the repository.

Answer (score 1):

To duplicate a repository without cloning it, in Github, you can refer to [this](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/) link.

Answer (score 1):

With local repositories :

```sh
git clone --no-hardlinks x x-new
cd x-new
git remote rm origin
```

With remote repositories :

```sh
git clone --bare /link/to/remote/x x-new
cd x-new
git push /link/to/remote/x-new --all
```

Answer (score 1):

The term "deep copy" is just wrong since - by default - any clone has all commits of the original repository.

What you want is "make another clone" (why) and change the URL to the new remote `x-new`.

```
git clone --no-local x x-new
git -C x-new remote set-url origin $URL_TO_REMOTE_X_NEW
```

However: If you have both a remote `x` and a remote `x-new` then just changing the URL of you **local** `x` would be enough. Optionally rename your local repo:

```
mv x x-new
git -C x-new remote set-url origin $URL_TO_REMOTE_X_NEW
```